# キーボードショートカットによる「質問の選択」は何のための機能ですか？

Tags: サポート

このサイトは、設定でキーボードショートカットを有効にすると以下の操作が可能になります。

> ```
> キーボードショートカット：
> G ページへ移動...
> U 質問を選択
> J 次の投稿を選択
> K 前の投稿を選択
> I 受信箱
> R 最近の実績
> S 検索
> ? ヘルプ
> H 自動ヘルプを無効にする
> ```

この中の、`J`や`K`で行なわれる「投稿を選択」という操作の使い方が解りません。選択することで可能になる操作がなにか有るのでしょうか。

Comment: 選択できるのはいいけど、その後になにか操作できるのか？って話ですかね。英語版や MSE を見て回ると "Enter で質問を開ける" みたいなコメントを見かけましたが、自分が試した限りでは「単に選択できるだけ」でした。["質問を開く" ショートカットを追加して欲しいという要望はありました](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367048) 。

Comment: Enterキーの押下で質問が開けない問題は、[すでにバグとして報告され status-review になっている](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375555)ようです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

既にコメントにも書かれているように、本来は `J` や `K` キーで**選択した質問へ、 `Enter` キー押下によって移動することができます**。しかし現在は UI 変更の影響で、 Enter キーによる質問ページへの移動が行えなくなる[バグが発生](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375555)しています。このため、現状では `J`, `K` キーの操作から発展して何かを行う、といったことは難しそうです。

バグが修正されれば、質問を開いた後に `L` キーで選択した投稿のリンクを取得したり、 `V` キーと `U` または `D` キーで選択した投稿へ投票したりなど、さまざまな応用的な操作が行えます：

> ```
> キーボードショートカット：
> G ページへ移動...
> U 質問を選択
> J 次の投稿を選択
> K 前の投稿を選択
> V 投票...
> A 回答
> E 編集
> T 再タグ
> C コメントを追加／表示
> L リンク
> M モデレート...
> I 受信箱
> R 最近の実績
> S 検索
> ? ヘルプ
> H 自動ヘルプを無効にする
> ```

Answer (score 3):

バグが直った模様です。現在は投稿を選択後、<kbd>Enter</kbd>（移動）及び、<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>（新しいタブで開く）が使用できます。